# why nginx handle post request error after add some rewrite and try_file patton?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use different page for PC and modile,but after add some if condition and rewrite pattern, I meet some new errors for post request to the APIS .
here is my nginx config

```
server {
listen 80 ;
server_name some;
gzip on;
gzip_types text/javascript;

location ^~ /v1 {
 proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
 proxy_pass http://market;
}
if ($is_pc) {
    rewrite ^/(?!pc/)(?!.*\.(js|css))(.*)$ /pc/dist/$1 last;
}
location / {
    root /etc/nginx/market/dist;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /pc/ {
    root /etc/nginx/market/;
    index /pc/dist/index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /pc/dist/index.html;
}
location ~ ^/assets/.*\.(js|css)$ {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ https://some.cdn/khd$1 permanent;
}
location ~ ^/pc/dist/assets/(.*\.(js|css))$ {
    rewrite ^/pc/dist/assets/(.*)$ https://some.cdn/khd/assets/$1 permanent;
}
```

}

when I open the page, it get an error when post to  /v1/productList with error http code 405
I do not know how nginx consider this post request as an request to static files.
and ideas how to fix this?
or any better way to do this?

Comment: Not sure where `$is_pc` is defined, but if it evaluates true, the `rewrite...last` will be executed before any `location` is chosen. You might consider moving the `if` block into `location /` - but take note of [additional restrictions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: thank you, $is_pc is defined in a common nginx.conf. After moving to the location /, fix my problem, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The [rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) (which includes `if`, `rewrite`, and `return`) will evaluate its directives in `server` context **before** Nginx select a `location` block to process a request.

So your `if (...) { rewrite...last; }` can change a URL that would ordinarily match `location ^~ /v1` into something that does not.

If the `if (...) { rewrite...last; }` block is moved into `location /`, Nginx will first select a `location` block to process a request, which means that URLs matching `location ^~ /v1` will no longer be rewritten by that code.

Be aware that `if` blocks within a `location` context have [additional restrictions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), however, `rewrite...last` is safe to use.